# Know the the frame number from frame rate and current normalized time

Tags: animation, math, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an animation that runs at 21 fps (frame per second) which has 180 frames and I know the normalized time (0->1) of each frame during the animation. I wonder how I can know the frame number if I only given the normalized time of that frame? Any advice please.

Comment: I saw your other question on this and wondered why you need to know the time of the animation?

Comment: @mGuv what other question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by :

```
        int frameNumber = Mathf.FloorToInt(normalizedtime* 180);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this Information, your Animation takes `180/21 = 8.57` aprox time to complete. So, you need to find timeOfFrame by

```
float timeOfFrame = 8.75f * normalizedTime;
```

and then frame number by

```
int frameNumber = (int) (timeOfFrame * 21);
```

so Actually it is derived as:

```
FrameNumber = NumberOfFrames * NormalizedTimeOfFrame
```

Comment: it's not working properly, and give big frame numbers. I'm expecting it to be 1,2,3,4.....

Comment: by frame number do you mean it between 1 and 180?